# How to check if a type alias exists in a type using concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Is there a way to require that a given type has a type alias defined within it? For example, how could I write a concept to check that this would be valid where the concept checks that the type T has a type alias `Bar`?

```
template <typename T>
concept HasBarType = ????;

template <HasBarType T>
void foo() {
    [[maybe_unused]] T::Bar bar;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
concept HasBarType = requires { typename T::Bar; };
```

This checks that `T::Bar` names a type. It can be a type alias in `T`, a nested class in `T`, a base class of `T` or the injected-class-name of `T` itself, though.

The `typename` keyword at the beginning makes this a *type-requirement* which has different semantics than the same line without `typename` or with additional braces instead.

With `typename` it requires `T::Bar` to name a type.

Without `typename` it is a *simple-requirement* which requires `T::Bar` to be a well-formed expression.

With additional braces, optionally followed by `-> type-constraint` it is a *compound-requirement* which requires the expression `typename T::Bar` to be well-formed and the result type of the expression to satisfy the specified *type-constraint*. (That's impossible because `typename T::Bar` doesn't have a valid form for an expression.)

You also need `typename` before `T::Bar` in the non-static data member, because `T::Bar` is dependent.

Comment: Ah I see where I went wrong. I mostly had that except I had an extra pair of parens inside the requires clause. What is the reason you'd need `requires { { something }; };` instead of just how you wrote it? Is it just to validate the output of the expressions against a concept? For example, the `Hashable` concept found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) has nested parens.

Comment: @Keltek That's a completely different kind of _requirement_. See my edit.